# How to sign a message with public key RSA

Tags: cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption, cryptojs

I'm new to cryptography and trying to perform simple RSA sign of the message with the public key.

```
const PublicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----GIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDCS7h56MiVTsV1SZ9gvWidH5XheZIpq1PUjKA//6m5N5HYkDtWQ9d+jx6niKDRUYf+aVc8StDKvIRJGT2ZZtIJ27FG9VpvZhR5yG38sh51MAPqZ/rpIzXg2Vj9dR2y3IUyWAafJ/VVGlecSYWREK1t6aMi7piHZpP/Rvn+1ImUTQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
const MessageKey = "4FSF5BE55B26FBABA402C23E1FF85E8F"
```

with a help of **jsrsasign** library I achieved this:

```
  const publicKey = RSA.KEYUTIL.getKey(PublicKey)
  const encrypted = RSA.KJUR.crypto.Cipher.encrypt(MessageKey, publicKey, "RSA")
  console.log(RSA.hextob64(encrypted))
```

But I'm afraid it's incorrect. Has someone performed encryption of message with public key in JS?

Comment: You don't _sign_ with a public key - you _encrypt_ with it.  You _sign_ with your private key as recipients can check that signature with your public key.

Answer (score 1):

sign with private key, encrypt with public key

to gen a pub key (with openssl and id_rsa):

```
openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -pubout > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.pem
```

to encrypt:

```
cat plain.txt | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.pem > cipher.txt
```

to decrypt:

```
cat cipher.txt | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```